# How to Deny access to one page when you are not logged in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, forms-authentication

I have a non logged web application that contain 50 pages, I need to have one logged page "testpage" How can do this:

```xml
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login/LoginExpiration.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Home/Default.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
<location path="testpage">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your config file location means not the page name but a folder.
Create a folder called testpage, place your page there and it will work